# How to send the email which is sleeping in my queue list?

Tags: linux, fedora, centos, email, sendmail

When i send email it sleep in my queue list. How can i send them out? (Fedora 15 distro).

```
# mailq
        /var/spool/mqueue (2 requests)
-----Q-ID----- --Size-- -----Q-Time----- ------------Sender/Recipient-----------
pBMNMDA1009288*    2100 Fri Dec 23 00:22 <apache@example>
                     <b@a.com>
pBMNIjU5009236     2100 Fri Dec 23 00:18 <apache@example>
                 (Deferred: Connection timed out with aspmx3.googlemail.com.)
                     <b@a.com>
```

Comment: Which MTA?  Sendmail, postfix, qmail, exim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever sendmail has to deliver mails to other hosts which cannot be reached at that time, the messages are kept in the queue and are marked as “Deferred: Connection timed out”. Although the other hosts could be reached again and you want to tell sendmail to flush the mail queue, the command
`sendmail -q -v`
does not really try to reconnect to these hosts and still assumes that the connection timed out. The reason is that the hoststatus is cached, per default for a period of 30 minutes. Using `sendmail -OTimeout.hoststatus=0m -q -v`
you can re-run the mail queue and force sendmail to reconnect to the hosts.

Alternatively, if you want to do a selective flush on perticular domain or user or recepitience mail to delete, use this command

```
  sendmail -qS -v apache # it will delete all mail from *@apache

  sendmail -qR -v a.com # it will delete all mail destined for recepient at user of a.com
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sendmail -q
```

(if sendmail or postfix is your mta)